# ImageDataFactory.Create from a UNC path throws exception

Tags: itext7

When i create a imagedata object from a unc path i get an 'iText.IO.IOException' when using a unc path to the image.

example:

```
ImageDataFactory.Create(@"\\servername\share\test.jpg");
```

exception:

```
iText.IO.IOException: 'I/O exception.'
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\share\test.jpg'.
```

The `'\\servername\'` part of the unc path is replaced by `'c:\'` by iText.

environment:

Windows 10 x64 EN
ItextSHarp version 7.0.5.0

Comment: `ImageDataFactory` has `Create(byte[] bytes)` method. You can simply read the contents of the file to the byte array and then use this `Create` method